# Bottom menu options

Tags: material-design, flutter, material-ui, flutter-layout

How can I achieve a simple bottom menu in Flutter? I want to show a set number of menu items and respond appropriately to clicks. I haven't been able to find anything in the [gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, with custom options (not just media options)

[image]

Comment: what about bottom sheet? https://flutterdoc.com/bottom-sheets-in-flutter-ec05c90453e7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/modal_bottom_sheet_demo.dart

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Modal bottom sheet')),
  body: new Center(
    child: new RaisedButton(
      child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) 
         {
          return new Container(
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
              child: ListView(
               children: <Widget>[
                 ListTile(title: Text('Map'),onTap:null),//handle on tap here
                 //build other menu here
                 ],
              );
                )
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  fontSize: 24.0
                )
              )
            )
          );
        });
      }
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWsQZ.jpg)

"I have previously written code which have the same ui of bottomsheet you can update this"

```
Future<void> _selectImage(BuildContext context) async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Upload a video to your workspace',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Divider(),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Take a photo',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 17,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Uint8List? file = await pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                        if (file != null) {
                          setState(() {
                            _file = file;
                            _isImageFullscreen = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    const Divider(),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Choose from gallery',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Uint8List? file = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                        if (file != null) {
                          setState(() {
                            _file = file;
                            _isImageFullscreen = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Card(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```